# Android Studio Running app is too late

Tags: android, android-emulator

**i have a problem when i am trying to run my app with a emulator that its 2 hours and it didn't started until now 
and this message was printed**

```
emulator: device fd:892
HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.
emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1536 MB
emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 512 MB
emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.
creating window 43 59 329 583
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: UpdateCheck: current version '24.4.0', last version '24.4.0'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you said '2 hours' with exaggeration.

First 1536 MB Ram for an emulator is too much. You can reduce it to 512 or lower. Also I suggest you to use [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) which is more faster and useful than standard android emulator (at least it my i3 device).

Using GenyMotion, I'm creating `320x480, Jell Bean` emulator with 512 MB RAM in 1-2 minutes.

Comment: how i can use GenyMotion in Android Studio!!

Answer (score 0):

When you create an emulator using the AVD choose advanced settings and change the RAM to 1536MB. or just edit you current device the same way.

Comment: try reinstalling HAXM and choose higher ram allocation during installation and put it to 2Gb of ram of you have them available.

Comment: How i can Re install it?!