# Android Studio Running app is too slow

Tags: android, android-studio

When i run my app, it takes about 10 min to display on my phone. And every change in code also takes 10 min. What should I do? I am using `Android Studio 2.0`.

Comment: due to `gradle` probably

Comment: *Instant Run* can reduce your pain somewhat!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136003/android-studio-running-app-is-too-late/33136142

Comment: how much memory do you have and are you running AVD?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623917/first-launch-take-long-time-in-android-studio-2-0-gradle-2-0/36625589#36625589

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/building-studio.html#instant-run

Comment: -Xms256m
-Xmx1280m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m

Answer (score 7):

In android studio goto

- **File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle** and check the  **Offline Work** option.
- **File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Compiler** and check all four checkboxes.

If you are using android 2.0 or higher and if you have enabled Instant Run.

- **File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant

     Run** and uncheck all four checkboxes.
  **
  Sometimes enabling Instant run causes app to launch activity too slowly with white screen after running. Disabling instant run will remove the problem.
- Restart Android studio

Comment: its not working . Still take too much time to load activity.

Comment: Have you restarted android studio?
If you have enabled Instant run try running after desabling it. Sometimes Instant run causes application to load activity very slowly with white screen after running app.

Comment: Now its work very fine. Thank you for suggestion @Megha

Comment: If it is working fine then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to the Android Studio 2.1. I also faced the same problem in 2.0

hope it will work.