# Android app slow when installed from Android Studio, but runs fine when installed from adb

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I'm not really sure how to word this.For some reason when I install an app that I'm working on from Android Studio it runs very slow (when an option is pressed it takes 10-20 seconds to register). But if I install the app from either my coworkers Android studio or adb from my own machine it works fine.

My specs are:
OS: Windows 10
Android Studio Version: 3.0.1
Phone OS: Android API 24

It was working fine this morning, but during the course of the day, something has happened. Has anyone run into this sort of problem before?

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S8 physical device. I have tried a factory reset on the phone which worked for one install after I changed some things I'm back where I started. I have also restarted both the machine and phone multiple times. I'm at a loss as to what is going on. If you guys need any more info let me know. Also INSTANT RUN IS NOT ON.

EDIT: I'm at a total loss as to why this is happening. I've tried everything from restoring the phone, reinstalling Android Studio, changing wires, changing settings, but nothing is working. If anyone has a suggestion I will gladly try anything.

Comment: I had a similar issue yesterday. I ended up rebuilding my Virtual Device from scratch. That helped.

Comment: I'm using a physical device. I did a factory reset and it worked for the first install, but I just changed something and loaded it up again and I'm back to square one.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found a solid solution to my problem. I'm positive now that something went wrong with m usb drivers for windows 10. I went to this page https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/windows-10-slow-usb-30-transfer-speeds/a5e1eebb-74bb-4777-8902-5131f3e8ec3e and I completed the steps in method 1 and that did the trick for me. it took a while to find this out, but hopefully, someone else will find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you compared your yesterday build and today build which is making your app slow. Any Significant change in code?

Comment: The changes made are not very significant. I even rolled back with git and it is still slow. I'm able to run my coworker's code fine if I get it from his computer. If I try the same thing on mine it is cripplingly slow. So this is the same app I'm installing but for some reason, it is very slow when installed by Android Studio on my pc.

Comment: Have you restarted your system/Laptop? If not give a try. Also found a link, they have same problem. and it got solved.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043579/android-studio-running-app-is-too-slow

Comment: Yes, I've already restarted the system and I have already tried the fix suggested but it, unfortunately, did not help. I just came in so maybe the long time off has helped the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up breakpoints or similar? Some debugging options can significantly slow the app down at runtime. When this happens, if you disconnect the phone from ADB - e.g. pull out the cable - and it speeds up again, then it's likely related to your debug connection to that particular instance of Android Studio.

Comment: There were no breakpoints and even if I disconnected the phone it would run slow. I think I managed to fix it by doing a Factory reset on the phone. I have no clue what happened.